# Django swapping field values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model I am developing locally like:

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        _('Non-sequential key for external lookups'),
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
    )
```

This resulted in a migration like:

```py
from django.db import migrations, models
import uuid

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('uuid', models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, verbose_name='Non-sequential key for external lookups')),
    ]
```

This was working great initially; objects I created had both an incrementing integer `id` and a `uuid` property, with `id` mapped to `pk`. Fast forward a week, and I need to rebuild the database to retest a migration script I'm writing. The script fails, and when I dig into it, I discover that the ID and UUID fields are swapped:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from my_model import MyModel
>>> item = MyModel.objects.first()
>>> item.pk
UUID('cee60e6b-aa2e-48a2-a34c-4315ebacea0b')
>>> item.id
UUID('cee60e6b-aa2e-48a2-a34c-4315ebacea0b')
>>> item.uuid
45384
```

Has anyone else ever run into anything like this? I'm baffled over what the heck is going on, or what might have changed. The database side looks fine (primary key on the `id` column, and unique index on the `uuid` column); it's just Django's mapping that's all screwy. I'm running Django 2.2.9.

Comment: Has anything changed in your model?

Comment: @IainShelvington I added some new, non-indexed fields since the last time I ran the migration script, but nothing that should have impacted the primary key. I'd tried reverting my repo and running the migrations again yesterday without seeing any difference, but when I went even farther back in time this morning it started working properly, though, so looks like I'm in for a slog through the past.

Answer (score 0):

It took some painstaking digging through git history, but I tracked down the mysterious issue that was plaguing me!

Turns out last week I needed to track a bit of info on this model object that was in-memory for Python but not persisted to the database. So I added a local property:

```py
from typing import Optional
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...Database column properties here...
    local_property: Optional[str] = None

    def __init__(self, local_property: Optional[str] = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_property = local_property
```

This caused the Django field association code to get offset or something. The fix was to pop my custom property out of the kwargs instead:

```py
from typing import Optional
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ...Database column properties here...
    local_property: Optional[str] = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        local_property = kwargs.pop('local_property', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_property = local_property
```